# Inconsistent error handling in VBA when throwing exceptions

Tags: vba, exception

I have a class `c1` that calls another class `c2`'s methods.  I want an error generated by `c2` to be caught and handled by `c1`, which will add the error's description to a collection.  Code for the relevant functions as follows:

c1:

```
Private Function doSomething(ByRef rs As DAO.Recordset) As Collection  

Dim errors as Collection

Set errors = New Collection

On Error GoTo logError

Do While Not rs.EOF
        c2.doSomethingElse rs!someValue
        GoTo continueLoop

logError:
        errors.Add (Err.Description)

continueLoop:
        rs.MoveNext
Loop

Set doSomething = errors

End Function
```

c2:

```
Public Sub doSomethingElse(someValue as string)  

If Not xyz(someValue) Then
    Err.Raise 516, "doSomethingElse", "xyz: " & someValue
Else
    DoOtherThings

End Sub
```

When I have set Error Trapping to "Break on Unhandled Errors", sometimes the `Err.Raise` in `doSomethingElse` will raise the error up to `doSomething`, but sometimes it will just halt execution with a run-time error as though `doSomething` doesn't have an `On Error` condition.  The first record in `rs` will usually result in the error being raised to `doSomething`, but the second one always results in a run-time error.  Sometimes the first record also throws a run-time error.

Is something happening after my first iteration of the `Do While` loop in `doSomething` that turns off error handling?

Answer (score 0):

Error handling will only do one error.

When rs.movenext sends the routine back through the loop, the error will not work anymore.

Put Resume continueLoop after your error handling.
The following code works for me.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  doSomething
End Sub

Private Function doSomething() As Collection
  Dim errors As Collection
  Set errors = New Collection

  On Error GoTo logError

  Do
    doSomethingElse ("someValue")
    GoTo continueLoop

logError:
    errors.Add (Err.Description)
    Resume continueLoop

continueLoop:

   Loop

   Set doSomething = errors

End Function

Public Sub doSomethingElse(someValue As String)    
    Err.Raise 516, "doSomethingElse", "xyz: " & someValue    
End Sub
```

Be sure to mark this as the right answer if it works for you.

Comment: I moved it inside the loop, but I'm getting the same result: first time works, then second time through the loop I get the run-time error with no handling.

Comment: It's the user-defined error that I threw in `doSomethingElse()`.

Comment: I tried your updated answer.  Still throwing an unhandled run-time error.

Comment: I just posted the whole test program that I was used.  It works for me - It traps the error every time through the loop.